# LINQ Except not returning string values correctly

Tags: c#, linq, compare, except, icacls

I've been trying to create a small program to compare two collections of strings and to output any items that are different or missing between collection1 and collection2.

As far as I have been able to determine LINQ's .Except method should provide my desired outcome but it seems to fall short.

The files which I'm trying to compare are the ACL files produced by using ICACLS to save all the permissions on a given directory and its subdirectories by running the following command from cmd:

```
icacls c:\TestHash /save c:\aclFile.txt /t
```

I run this command twice on a directory to produce two icacls files which I want to ensure match and if they don't then I want to output where they don't match.

Here is some sample code for trying to compare these items

```
  //Load in user permissions files
            var list1 = File.ReadAllLines(dbFilePath1, Encoding.Unicode);
            var list2 = File.ReadAllLines(dbFilePath2, Encoding.Unicode);
```

Once the items were loaded I'd run the .Except command

```
  //Identify all differences between the two collections and output to new collection
            var list3 = list1.Except(list2);
            var list4 = list2.Except(list1);
```

However, here is an example below of 10 records from file 1 in which I remove one permissions record from file 2 but .Except doesn't identify that it's missing the item

First file:

```
TestHash
D:AI(A;OICIID;FA;;;BC)(A;OICIID;FD;;;SY)(A;OICIID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)
TestHash\testFile1.csv
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BD)(A;ID;FR;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)
TestHash\testFile2.csv
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BD)(A;ID;FR;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)
TestHash\testFile3.csv
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BD)(A;ID;FR;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)
TestHash\testFile4.csv
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BD)(A;ID;FR;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)
```

Second file:

```
TestHash
D:AI(A;OICIID;FA;;;BC)(A;OICIID;FD;;;SY)(A;OICIID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)(A;OICIIOID;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)
TestHash\testFile1.csv
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BD)(A;ID;FR;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)
TestHash\testFile2.csv
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BD)(A;ID;FR;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)
TestHash\testFile3.csv
TestHash\testFile4.csv
D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BD)(A;ID;FR;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1307by;;;AU)
```

As described above the second file is missing one permissions record but .Except doesn't recognise this, the collections are being processed as an enumeration of strings and the default equality comparer should be able to detect this difference as far as I can understand, I'm aware you can override this with a custom comparer but I'm not sure on what the implementation would be for this.

An additional note is that this only seems to throw up issues with any of the permissions strings themselves, .Except does seem able to determine any missing strings when it's one of the folder/file names, so I'm thinking it may be getting confused because there are many identical permissions strings within the collection so it may think it's got a matching item even though it's not got a specific record relating to a specific file.

I expect this will need some sort of custom override but I'm not sure what this implementation would be.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated, thanks for taking the time to read this through.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code, errors, or sample text when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612). To make this answerable, you should [edit] the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: I think it's intended behaviour of except? `list2.Except(list1);` shows items in list2 that is different with list1. You deleted the line in list2, hence it doesn't show up.

Comment: If list1 has an additional item then the difference should be returned that the collection has an extra record that isn't in the second collection, it outputs this if I remove a file/folder name so I know it works in that case, it just doesn't seem to recognise this for the permissions strings

Comment: Can someone explain why this was voted down? :(

Comment: If you look at the implementation of except (e.g. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,892) , you can easily see why this does not work

Comment: "This method returns those elements in first that don't appear in second. It doesn't return those elements in second that don't appear in first. Only unique elements are returned."

Comment: A library like https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex/ might be useful in this situation.

Comment: @MarkHomer yes but I call it on both collections so it should return that element from the first list that doesn't appear in the second list, if I removed one of the file/folder name values it works fine, but it doesn't when it's one of the permissions lines

Comment: @sgmoore thanks for linking that implementation detail, I'm still struggling to understand why this isn't working though.

Comment: @Waves "...Only unique elements are returned."

Comment: @MarkHomer so what makes an element unique? because whilst there are other values that contain the same characters, it should still be considered a unique record in this context or rather, how do I return the non-unique elements as well because I need to return all differences.

Comment: Try `(new int[] { 1, 2, 2 }).Except( new int[] { 1, 2 })` to see what except does, it simply checks that 1 is in the second list, which it is, then it checks that 2 is in the second list which it is and then checks again that 2 is in the second list which it is. It does not check that the number of times that 2 occurs in the second list is the same as the number in the first list. In your case, your 'missing' permission is actually in the second list and hence not really missing.

Comment: @sgmoore thank you for your explanation, I'm understanding why this isn't working,, for my purposes I need to find a way to catch these differences though so I'm wondering now if there's a way of doing this with LINQ or a loop through the collections to achieve this however I'm not sure on what the implementation would be ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if my assumptions are correct, but it looks like the format of the file generated is two lines per directory entry and that the first line is the full path to the file and hence must be unique.

If that is correct, then the second list can not contain the line `TestHash\testFile3.csv`.

If so then you can group the directory entry with the permission and then use except to check for differences.

To do this, I first add a line number to each line and then group by every two lines and the create an anonymous object with the first and second entries in each group,

eg

```
var groupedList1 = list1
    .Select((val , index) => new { val, index })
    .GroupBy(g => g.index / 2)
    .Select(r => r.ToArray())
    .Select(r => new { DirectoryEntry = r[0].val , OldPermission = r[1].val , NewPermission = ""}) ;
```

Because the DirectoryEntry Name is unique, we know that each entry in our grouped list must be unique and hence the except operator will operator as you want.

Or you could combine groupedList1 and groupedList2 like

```
var allEntries = groupedList1.Select(a=>a.DirectoryEntry).Union(
                 groupedList2.Select(a=>a.DirectoryEntry));

var combined = (from r in allEntries select new 
    { 
       DirectoryEntry =  r , 
       OldPermission = groupedList1.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.DirectoryEntry == r)?.Permission , 
       NewPermission = groupedList2.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.DirectoryEntry == r)?.Permission 
    }
    )
    .Where(a=>a.OldPermission != a.NewPermission);
```